# Tableau - Find time difference between two colums

Tags: time, tableau-api

I have two columns of data:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| StartTime               | FinishTime              |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2015.09.06 12:56:03 GMT | 2015.09.06 12:56:30 GMT |
| ...                     | ...                     |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I want another column to calculate duration.

I used DataDiff Function in Tableau, but i am getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data you showed, I'm guessing you want the difference in seconds between the times. You're right to use `DATEDIFF()`. (I noticed you said DAT**A**DIFF, so careful that you're using the right method.)

Use the following calculated field:

```
DATEDIFF('second', [StartTime], [FinishTime])
```

Adjust that first argument accordingly if I guessed wrong on the unit of time you want.

---

### Edit to address comments:

If Tableau's having trouble automatically parsing `StartTime` and `EndTime` as datetimes, you can use `DATEPARSE()`:

```
DATEPARSE("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss", [StartTime])
```

As for displaying the duration in hours, minutes, and seconds, `DATEDIFF()` just returns a single number, so you'll have to homebrew something. You'll need to create your own function so you can format the duration according to your needs, but here's one quick example that displays the duration as "hh:mm:ss" (you'll need to make a calculated field like I showed above to find the duration in seconds first):

```
RIGHT('0' + STR(FLOOR([Duration in Seconds]/60/60)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + STR(FLOOR([Duration in Seconds]/60)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + STR(FLOOR([Duration in Seconds])), 2)
```

On each line, you divide the duration in seconds by the appropriate divisor to convert to hours, minutes, or seconds. Then you `FLOOR` that number to trash the decimal. To deal with single digit numbers, you concatenate a '0' to the front of each number, then take the right two characters of the resulting string. (`RIGHT('027', 2)` yields `'27'`, and `RIGHT('04', 2)` yields `'04'`.)

Comment: i want in hour, minute and seconds... is that possible?? and Start time and End time is in string format. When i tried to change datatype, the column only returned null values. Dateparse function doesn't properly convert. Can anyone specify how to convert this to DateTime function so that i can use DateDiff

Comment: @blackfury, are all of your times GMT?

Answer (score 0):

Following will give an output **(duration:1h 2m 11s)**

> "(duration:" + 
>   STR(CEILING(DATEDIFF('minute',[start_date],[end_date])/60)-1)+"h "+
>   STR(DATEDIFF('minute',[start_date],[end_date]) -
>      ((CEILING(DATEDIFF('minute',[start_date],[end_date])/60)-1) * 60 )) + "m " + 
>   STR(DATEDIFF('second',[start_date],[end_date]) % 60) + "s)"